# Images are not migrated and the body field is empty

Tags: 8, migrations

I tried to migrate a site from Drupal 7 to Drupal 8.1 using drush (migrate-import --all) and the following modules:

- Migrate Plus
- Migrate Tools
- and the D8 core migrate modules.

It doesn't migrate the image of my nodes and the body field is empty. Do I have to create the same content types with similar fields first, or should I let the Migrate module do this?

The empty body looks like a problem with the text format filter. I use the full HTML text format with CkEditor on Drupal 7, but this filter exists on Drupal 8 too, so I don't understand why it happens.

Answer (score 1):

The solution for the body-field:

it must be a translation problem. I changed the language of the Drupal 8.1 site to the same language as the Drupal 7 site and now the body field isn't empty anymore.

But the images are still missing. I noticed that no files were imported. Under /admin/content/files there is nothing! any help in this case?

Answer (score 1):

Body field of Node is a compound field so we define body field like this in .yml file.

```
process:
......
......
  'body/format':
    plugin: static_map
    bypass: true
    source: body_format
    map:
      1: plain_text
      2: restricted_html
      3: full_html
      4: full_html
  'body/value': body_value
  'body/summary': body_summary
```

Also in php class file that extends SqlBase for migration you need to define body.

```
public function fields() {
    $fields = $this->baseFields();
    $fields['body/format'] = $this->t('Format of body');
    $fields['body/value'] = $this->t('Full text of body');
    $fields['body/summary'] = $this->t('Summary of body');
    return $fields;
  }
```